# Yii 2: Add prompt text field on clicking on GridView

Tags: javascript, gridview, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I've created action onClick  in GridView  and it redirects me to an action in controller.

Code in Index.php:

```
},
  'rowOptions' => function ($model, $key, $index, $grid) {
      return ['id' => $model['id'], 'onclick' => 'var myid=this.id; var enteredValue = prompt("Please enter a number");  
        window.location.href = "index.php?r=patientservices%2Fpassing" + "&id=myid, " + enteredValue; '];
},
```

In my Controller code:

```
public function actionPassing($id,$price)
{

    $ser= $this->findModel($id); 
    $model = new Receipts();
    $countclinic=Receipts::find()
                ->where(['patient_services_id'=>$id])
                ->count(); 

        if ($countclinic== 0) { 

         $model->patient_id=$ser->patient_id;
         $model->price=$price;  // the price that i need to pass
         $model->doctor_id=$ser->doctor_id;
         $model->patient_services_id=$ser->id;

         $model->reg_date=DATE('y-m-d h:m:s');
         $model->description='دفعة تحت الحساب';
         $model->userin =  \Yii::$app->user->identity->id ;
         $model->save();

            $models = $this->findModel($id);
            $models->state=2;
            $models->save();
```

JS Code :

```
$this->registerJs("
$('.custom_button').on('click', function() {

    alert(id);
    var enteredValue = prompt('Please enter a number');
    if (enteredValue != null) {
        window.location.href = 'index.php?r=patientservices%2Fpassing' + '&id=, ' + enteredValue;
    }
});
");
```

What I need is:
When the user clicks on the Row  in GridView a prompt text appears for the user and the number inserted in the prompt text is passed with the ID to controller to use it there but the js code pass the id as a character not like number

> $model->price=$ser->price;

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can do it:

1. Instead of using link, use `#` as a link since you don't want to redirect user just yet.
2. After user clicks on button, you want to "summon" a prompt. This can be achieved by JavaScript/jQuery only.
3. Inside the JavaScript/jQuery code you can insert PHP code, too, and form an URL.

For example (in GridView):

```
'buttons' => [
    'passing' => function () {
        return Html::a('Content', '#', [
            'class' => 'btn btn-primary custom_button',
            'title' => 'تسجيل القيمة كـ إيصال',
        ]);
    },
],
```

Then at the end of file:

```
$this->registerJs("
    $('.custom_button').on('click', function() {
        var enteredValue = prompt('Please enter a number');
        if (enteredValue != null) {
            window.location.href = '".$url."' + '&id= ' + enteredValue;
        }
    });
");
```

Worth to note I have included a class `custom_button` since we want to know if the button user clicked is the correct one, not any.

Comment: there is small issue ..  the function that in controller should include `($id,$price)` the js code doesn't get the id of my row and i didn't get how to get it or add it to my custom_button  then use it in passed id in js code

Comment: @NaeemAli You can get `$id` and `$price` by passing `$model` as parameter. For example, `'passing' => function ($model) {` and `'data-price' => $model->price` in array in GridView. Then in JS: `window.location.href = '".$url."' + '&id= ' + enteredValue + '&price=' + $(this).data('price');`

Comment: Dear @Edvin there is something wrong I used this code :  `'passing' => function ($model) {
                return Html::a('Content', '#', [
                'class' => 'btn btn-primary custom_button',
                'data-price' => $model->price,
                'title' => 'تسجيل القيمة كـ إيصال',` and then when i try it it gives me  `Trying to get property of non-object`

Comment: It doesn't necessarily mean `$model`, it should be the same as you use as `searchModel` in GridView.

Comment: Sorry `Undefined variable: searchModel`

Comment: I've changed my idea i just need to pass id and price by clicking on the row  `'rowOptions' => function ($model, $key, $index, $grid) {
                return ['id' => $model['id'], 'onclick' => 'var myid=this.id; var enteredValue = prompt("Please enter a number");  
                                                       
            window.location.href = "index.php?r=patientservices%2Fpassing" + "&id=myid, " + enteredValue; '];
        },` but it doesn't  pass the id

Comment: It's got complicated. Not sure now. :|

Comment: i changed my idea coz I thought its more easier ... it was giving me  errors ... so can you give me full answer ?

Comment: I've  changed the whole idea . I just add a new text in the form for the price and pass the value  with it to the recipts table  ... I sloved my problem.  Thank you.